# c++ function that takes any data type without using templates?

Tags: c++, templates

I have assignment which asks one to write a function for any data type.The function is supposed to print the bytes of the structure and identify the total number of bytes the data structure uses along with differentiating between bytes used for members and bytes used for padding.

My immediate reaction, along with most of the classes reaction was to use templates. This allows you to write the function once and gather the run time type of the objects passed into the function. Using memset and typeid's one can easily accomplish what has been asked. However, our prof. just saw our discussion about templates and damned templates to hell.

After seeing this I was thrown for a loop and I'm looking for a little guidance as the best way to get around this. Some things I've looked into:

- void pointers with explicit casting (this seems like it'd get messy)
- base class with virtual functions only from which all data structures inherit from, seems a bit odd to do.
- a base class with 'friendships' to each of our data structures.
- rewriting a function for each data structure in our problem set (what I imagine is the worst possible solution).

Was hoping I overlooked a common c++ tool, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If your **C++** instructor damned templates to hell, I sincerely hope it isn't too late to drop the class for a different instructor. Something should be damned to hell, to be sure, but it isn't templates.

Comment: This is not possible even with templates. The compiler (barring some non-standard extension) does not provide sufficient runtime information to determine the exact details of the layout of a type without knowing something about it.

Comment: What exactly is your goal? To dissect the raw memory of a structure into member and padding bytes?

Comment: Was your instructor looking for a generic platform-independent solution? or is there something *specific* (like the debug-ouutput of MS' compiler that throws-up layout info during compilation). The latter requirement, affectively dissection via `offsetof`, is, as @DarkFalcon stated not something you can do without specifying members in-code unless you hook in to the compilation process itself.

Comment: How would `memset` help you, even if you were using templates?

Comment: You might be able to do this a macro, but that wouldn't be 1) a function, or 2) C++ (it'd be C really).

Comment: templates are the only portable approach, and even then only if you savagely constrain the problem: you'd need to know the identifiers for all the potential data members in your type, so you could call sizeof and offsetof, but some things won't work anyway (`union`s, bit fields).  That is, you can write a templated function to get this kind of information for the set of types that may have specific data members (and no others).  C++ has no Standard facilities for introspection a type though, so you can't portably enumerate/iterate the data members when you just don't know their names.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: you can only do "it" with macros if you use the macros to generate the types the function will operate on and some meta-data thereon (doesn't sound like what the question's asking)... you can't take an existing normally-defined type and use a macro to get any introspective capabilities.

Comment: @Marcel-Is-Hier: no you couldn't... Variant and void pointers are of no use here... why did you think they might be?

Comment: Another example of some constraints that allow this to some extent... if you knew the types all sported constructors that set all the non-`static` data members to some value or other, you could hack at this by placement-`new`ing an object in an all-bits-0 buffer, then in an all-bits-1 buffer, and bits that change in either are *likely* part of the data representation, other bits *likely* padding, but again it's just an educated guess as the compiler's not required to leave padding bytes alone.  Are you sure you're not missing part of the scenario?

Comment: @TonyD naw, `#define stupid_macro(x){int i;const char* x_ptr=reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&(x));std::cout << sizeof((x)) << std::endl;    for (i=0; i < sizeof((x)); i++,x_ptr++) printf("%02x",*x_ptr);std::cout << std::endl;}`

Comment: How on earth would templates help solving this case at all ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust `template <typename T>
int stupid_template(const T& x)
{
  int i;
  const char* x_ptr=reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&(x));
  std::cout << sizeof(T) << std::endl;
  for (i=0; i < sizeof(T); i++,x_ptr++)
    printf("%02x",*x_ptr);
  std::cout << std::endl;
}`

Comment: @TonyD (But that method is like, super bad. If x is a rhr it'll go out of scope pretty quick. You could avoid this by making an auto copy at the beginning of the loop, but if the prof hates templates than he probably hates auto, and it wouldn't work on no-copy classes.)

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: indeed, the template helps getting the sizeof of the struct.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: that prints the total datatype size in bytes and the current bytes in memory - it doesn't give *any* insight into which bits are used by data members vs. which are padding.  The template version preserves the lifetime of x properly - won't go out of scope - but again: it's not doing what this questions asks for.

Comment: This is no such an absurd question as it looks first. I remember having had to write a message channel between a big-endian and little-endian system. For this to be possible, you need to find out the exact layout of the fields, padding inclusive, as the fields must be swapped individually.

Answer (score 1):

Treat the function as stupid as possible, in fact, treat it as if it doesn't know anything and all information must be passed to it.

Parameters to the function:

- Structure address, as a `uint8_t *`. (Needed to print the bytes)
- Structure size, in bytes. (Needed to print the bytes and to print the
  total size)
- A vector of member information:  member length OR the sum of the bytes used by the members.

The vector is needed to fulfill the requirement of printing the bytes used by the members and the bytes used by padding.  Optionally you could pass the sum of the members.

Example:

```
  void Analyze_Structure(uint8_t const *  p_structure,
                         size_t           size_of_structure,
                         size_t           size_occupied_by_members);
```

The *trick* of this assignment is to figure out how to have the calling function determine these items.

Hope this helps.

**Edit 1:**

```
struct Apple
{
  char    a;
  int     weight;
  double  protein_per_gram;
};

int main(void)
{
  Apple granny_smith;
  Analyze_Structure((uint8_t *) &granny_smith,
                    sizeof(Apple),
                    sizeof(granny_smith.a)
                    + sizeof(granny_smith.weight)
                    + sizeof(granny_smith.protein_per_gram);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"as a `uint8_t *`. (Needed to print the bytes)"* Can violate the strict aliasing rule. There are exceptions for the `char` types.

Comment: `sizeof(Apple::a)` is valid C++ (since C++11), no need for an object.

Comment: @dyp A valid *C++11* you mean.

Comment: `sizeof(granny_smith)==sizeof(granny_smith.a)+sizeof(granny_smith.weight)+sizeof(granny_smith.protien_per_gram)`, providing `granny_smith` is a value type and not a reference type.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams No, you don't account for padding.

Comment: @Constructor Ah, I knew there was an extension to the rules of `sizeof` in C++11, I couldn't remember what it was. Thanks, comment edited.

Comment: @pmr Very True. That brings up the point that the sizeof the members and not the padding is sort of a useless metric.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Why? It is actually a very helpful metric to figure out how well your structures are laid out on a certain platform. But this has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams:  The padding (alignment) issue with a structure has been around before C++, in the days of C.

Answer (score 1):

> I have assignment which asks one to write a function for any data type.

This means either templates (which your prof. dismissed), void*, or variable number of arguments (simiar to printf).

> The function is supposed to print the bytes of the structure

```
void your_function(void* data, std::size_t size)
{
    std::uint8_t* bytes = reinterpret_cast<std::uint8_t*>(data);

    for(auto x = bytes; x != bytes + size; ++x)
        std::clog << "0x" << std::hex << static_cast<std::uint32_t>(*x) << " ";
}
```

> [...] and identify the total number of bytes the data structure uses along with differentiating between bytes used for members and bytes used for padding.

On this one, I'm lost: the bytes used for padding are (by definition) not part of the structure. Consider:

```
struct x { char c; char d; char e; }; // sizeof(x) == 3;

x instance{ 0, 0, 0 };
your_function(&instance, sizeof(x)); // passes 3, not 4 (4 for 32bits architecture)
```

Theoretically, you could also pass `alignof(instance)` to the function, but that won't tell you the alignment of the fields in memory (as far as I know it is not standardized, but I may be wrong).

There are a few possibilities here:

1. Your prof. learned "hacky" C++ that was considered good code 10 or 20 years ago and didn't update his knowledge (C-style code, pointers, direct memory access and "smart hacks" are all in here).
2. He didn't know how to express exactly what he wanted or the terminology to use ("write a function for any data type" is too vague: as a developer, if I got this assignment, the first thing to do would be to ask for details - like "how will it be used?" and "what is the expected function signature").

   For example, this could be achieved - to a degree - with macros, but if he wants you to use macros in place of functions and templates, you should probably contemplate changing professors.
3. He meant that you should write some arbitrary data type (like my `struct x` above) and define your API around that (unlikely).

Comment: *"the bytes used for padding are (by definition) not part of the structure"* I'm not sure what you mean here. `sizeof` and `alignof` have to be compatible with pointer arithmetic (within an array), so any padding shows in the `sizeof` the structure.

Comment: Bytes for padding ARE part of the structure. It's just that in your example padding isn't needed (in most architectures). Try with
struct test { char i; int j; }; which outputs 8 for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that such a function can be built without a minimum of introspection: you need to know what the struct members are, otherwise you only have access to the size of the struct.

Anyway, here is my proposal for a solution that should work without introspection, provided the user of the code "cooperates".

Your functions will take as arguments void* and size_t for the address and sizeof of the struct.

0) let the user create a struct of the desired type.

1) let the user call a function of yours that sets all bytes to 0.

2) let the user assign a value to every field of the struct.

3) let the user call a function of yours that keeps a record of every byte that is still 0.

4) let the user call a function of yours that sets all bytes to 1.

5) let the user assign a value to every field of the struct again. (Same values as the first time!)

6) let the user call a function of yours and count the bytes that are still 1 AND were marked before. These are padding bytes.

The reason to try with values 0 then 1 is that the values assigned by the user could include bytes 0; but they can't be bytes 0 and bytes 1 at the same time so one of the test will exclude them.

```
struct _S { int I; char C } S;

Fill0(S, sizeof(S));

// User cooperation
S.I= 0;
S.C= '\0';

Mark0(S, sizeof(S)); // Has some form of static storage

Fill1(S, sizeof(S));

// User cooperation
S.I= 0;
S.C= '\0';

DetectPadding(S, sizeof(S));
```

You can pack all of this in a single function that takes a callback function argument that does the member assignments.

```
void Assign(void* pS) // User-written callback
{
  struct _S& S= *(struct _S)pS;

  S.I= 0;
  S.C= '\0';
}
```